# Vue Js Component issue- manipulating data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I've been devloping a project for a class and run into a problem where the components arent communicating well together as intended. The goal is that if there is one false in any component that it sends the message dont go to the location.
This is some of the code I currently have:

```
    <template>
    <div class="component">
        <h3>Temperature Sensor</h3>

        <input v-model = 'temperature' @keyup.enter = "checkTemp"> </input>
        <p> Action to take : {{ action }} </p>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from '../main.js';
export default {

    props :{ 
        action : String
    },
    computed () {
        return {
            //defines a movement value that we will use.
            movement : true,
        };
    },
    mounted(){
        eventBus.$on('move',(movement) =>{
           this.movement = movement;
           if(movement == true){
               this.action = "Go to Location";
           }else{
               this.action = "Dont go There";
           }
        })
    },
    methods : {

        checkTemp(){
            if(this.temperature >=50){
                this.movement = false;
                console.log(this.movement);
                eventBus.$emit('move', this.movement);
            }else {
                this.movement = true;
                console.log(this.movement);
                eventBus.$emit('move', this.movement);
            }
        }
    },

};
</script>

<style scoped>
    div {
        background-color: lightcoral;
    }
</style>
```

And for the second component:

```
    <template>
    <div class="component">
        <h3> Radiation Drone</h3>
       <input v-model = 'radiation' @keyup.enter = "checkRadiation"></input>
        <p > Action : {{ action }} </p>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from '../main.js';

export default {
    props : {

        action : String
    },
    computed () {
        return {
            movement : true,
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        eventBus.$on('move',(movement) =>{
           this.movement = movement;
           if(movement == true){
               this.action = "Go to Location";
           }else{
               this.action = "Dont go There";
           }
        })
    },
    methods : { 
      checkRadiation(){

              if(this.radiation >=34){
                  this.movement = false;
                  console.log(this.movement);
                 eventBus.$emit('dontGo',this.movement);
              }
                else {
                  this.movement = true;
                  console.log(this.movement);
                  this.$root.$emit('goThere',this.movement);
              }

          }
      },
};

</script>

<style scoped>
    div {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
</style>
```

It is showing an error of not manipulating the prop directly I just dont know how to refactor my code.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t change the prop value directly from the child component, instead use [emit](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) to call a method created in the parent components

Comment: So I would emit the method proper, modify it in the other component and use it there or how would that work?

Comment: Yes!, check this fiddle that I made: https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/ukrz98x3/